# Best Way to update all vertices data in openGL and to recalculate normals

Tags: opengl, 3d, vbo

Q1: I have a 3D model which has a vertex array. each element has x,y and z values.
Now I have created a dynamic vbo buffer to render this array in OpenGL. The problem 
is that I have to update all the vertices each frame [ which depends on some logic. but its for sure that it is not a simple transformation: I mean it cannot be done using a single transformation matrix for all vertices ].Now for each frame I map the vbo buffer then update the data and unmap it,
and then render it.
The update is done in a for loop.
Now I was wondering is there any faster way to do that?

Some points:
I have to update all vertices. Its my requirement, I cannot work with a subset of vertices.

Q2: I have to recalculate the normals because the vertices has been updated.and for smooth shading
I need to take the resultant of all the normals at a vertex which is slow.
Is there any faster way to do so?
Basically faster recalculation of normals for smooth shading.

Some things which I already know:

1. Use of SSE to optimize the normal calculation.
2. Use of TBB or openMP to parallelize loops.

Comment: CUDA (or openCL) could be an option, suppose you know that though

Comment: well for cuda you need nvidia GPU but openCL is good but will it solve both the problems? or it is good enough for normal recalculation, I mean is there any limitations to kind of calculation we can do with OpenCL ?

Comment: i havnt actually used openCL, only CUDA. but GPU parallelism can speed up these types of calculations up to 10x with some naive coding, and 100x+ when you really optimize things.

Answer (score 1):

I think that Transform Feedback is what you are looking for.

Using transform feed back, you can modify your vertex data during runtime and use it for another rendering , and all these operations can be achieved from GPU itself inside a vertex shader using transform feedback.

And it is supported in Opengl 3.0 and above.

[Here](http://prideout.net/blog/?tag=opengl-transform-feedback) is a simple example for how to use transfrom feedback.

[here](http://www.g-truc.net/post-0269.html) is some details about feedback buffer usage.

Comment: that looks much better than using CUDA or OpenCL. very interesting

Comment: Basically we will give the logic behind the update of a vertex in the shader progam which then will be used by GPU to update a vertex ?

Comment: @Ujjwal, yes add the code in vertex pgm for processing vertex data & feedback the needed iformations to a buffer object & use it for next time.